# No mapping exists from object type c#

Tags: c#, json, webmethod

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SaveLayout(string layout, object state)
    {



        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=admin123;Initial Catalog=Test_Layout;Data Source=Myserver");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertlayout", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@layout", layout);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@states", state);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return "successfully state saved";
    }
}
```

i am using **webmethod(using Json,jquery)** to store object in sql server 2008 
but i am getting following error on sql server 2008 i am using **varchar(max)** datatype for storing **object(state variable)** in database **how to convert state variable(object) to string** to store in database

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have to pass a string instead of dictionary. I may suggest you to serialise your dictionary and pass that value to `AddWithValue` function. Let JSON be the format of serialisation. I would recommend [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) as serialization library. It provides convenient way of dictionary [serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm)/[deserialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).

So your code may look like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@states", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state));
```

*P.S. better use `using` statement both for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store any object use `VARBINARY(MAX)` in sqlserver like

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@states", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);

sqlCmd.Parameters["@states"].Value = state;
```

here `state` will be your object